# Ubuntu crashes a minute after startup

Tags: crash, nvidia-geforce, visual-artifacts

Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit graphically crashes (maybe even crashes entirely, I don't know how to tell) after 1-2 minutes of use, it's a computer I built just so I can emulate retro stuff on my TV. The specs are:

AMD Athlon II, 3GB RAM DDR2, GeForce 7025

[image: this is what happens,]

I have tried with more lightweight flavours and different distros with no change in results, but just because it runs pretty good on Ubuntu and I like the distro as a whole if I can get it fixed it's better on this distro than any other.

Comment: What happens when you choose the recovery option low graphics mod of grub?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bad video card.  Not clear if the graphics is on the mobo or on a PCI card.  In any case, the latest drivers for series 7 can be found at http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/51453

Obviously, you want to check your cooling situation, fans not working, clogged filters and so on.  This sounds like a classic overheating problem.

Since the video is quitting on you, it might be easier to work on it if you can ssh into it from a different machine.  Also, trying a different video card could help.  Based on your question it looks like the OS itself is not crashing.  Just the video out is losing sync.

One way to completely eliminate drivers as the issue would be to liveCD a different operating system such as Windows.  Even booting memtest from CD / DVD ought to do it.  I have Tor on a thumbdrive as a test tool for things like this.  Your symptoms make it seem highly likely that the problem is defective hardware but I've included troubleshooting steps above to help prove or eliminate that possibility.

Comment: It does crash, i can't do anything at all when the screen turns that way, sleep the screen or open a terminal, it's abolutely gone when the screen turns that way. everything is on a small case from a 2007-8-9 pc, its almost silent so i guess its fairly clean and cold inside, it has 1 fan (other than the ones the processor and the power supply have) but its small, it does not use a lot of power so i want to believe its enough. i will put those drivers on a usb and hope it doesn't crash when it's installing.

Comment: Just because the video has gone haywire does not mean that the OS has crashed.  It may well have but I'm skeptical.  That's why in my answer I included trying to ssh in to the laptop from a different computer.  If that worked, you'd be confident that you're dealing with only a video problem.  Yours is an old, not especially powerful laptop.  You may find out that you just have a piece of bad hardware in it and that it's not economical to have it fixed.